# Location restricted Facebook apps - Possible to restrict view from page admins?

Tags: facebook, location, admin, restriction

We have created a Facebook application that is restricted to US only, using the Graph API location restriction method (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/574/).

This application has then been added to a Facebook page. However, it appears that admins of the page are still able to see the application, regardless of their location.

So our question is: would it be possible to disallow access to admins of the page if they are outside of the US?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, is it admins, or just because you are the owner of the app.

I have no experience with the restriction functionality but if the above still proves that page admins can view it, then it looks like page admin's can still view it. But there are some other steps you can apply considering people can easily fake location on Facebook anyway.

**IP Location**

Download GeoIP (free IP address database) and you can lock people out of your app that way as well.

**Graph API**

Connect to the graph API with their user Id, manually get their location and block based on that.

Or you can use a combination of all of the above.

Comment: And to answer your question, it's admins of the page. I tested with an account that has no specific role associated with the app (admin, tester, etc.), but with admin privs for the page, and was able to see the app.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely intentional - page admins will always see the tabs on their page - there's no way to hide content on a page from the admins of that page.

Broadly, there should be no way to hide content from users who are responsible for that content